# Filtering data and training multiple different models simultaneously with PySpark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, user-defined-functions, distributed-computing

I'm working on a Python code where, for each Xi object of a smaller dataset, I filter a much larger dataset, taking
those objects that are most similar to Xi (almost a neighborhood analysis), and train an SVM model (from sklearn) with that subset.
That is, I produce a model for each object in the smaller set from the data in the larger set.

This code works for what I'm doing, but it's slow and the size of the sets I can work with is limited.
That's why I'd like to distribute the storage and execution of the filter and training of the models.

Researching about it, I started to wonder if it would be possible to do this through PySpark UDFs.

Would something like this be possible with PySpark? Does anyone have any references to something similar that has already been done (not only with Spark)?

Comment: Very value, try explaining graphically.

Comment: vague I meant to say, but UDF is not the way to go.

Comment: @WillMon did you find a solution to this?